# If combined width of elements < body change a div's ID?

Tags: jquery

I need to get the combined width of a set of divs (.image-div), and if their combined width is less than the body's width then change the ID of `#makeMeScrollable` to `#makeMeScrollable2`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#makeMeScrollable').each(function() {
        var totalImageWidth = 0;

        $(".image-div", this).each(function () {
          totalImageWidth += $(this).width();
        });

    if (totalImageWidth < body ) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'makeMeScrollable2');
    }

    });
});
```

If I replace 'body' with a static number the code works so I must almost be there. I think this is just a syntax issue but I've tried every variation I can think of.

UPDATE Thanks to @ShankarSangoli ive got it working with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#makeMeScrollable').each(function() {
    var totalImageWidth = 0;

    $(".image-div", this).each(function () {
      totalImageWidth += $(this).width();
    });

    if (totalImageWidth < $(document.body).width() ) {
       $(this).attr('id', 'makeMeScrollable2');
    }

});
});
```

But is their a way of changing this line like this?:

```
if (totalImageWidth - 1000 < $(document.body).width() ) {
```

Comment: maybe you need to get the `width` of the body. What is the variable 'body'?

Comment: `if ( totalImageWidth < $( window ).width() ) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#makeMeScrollable').each(function() {
        var totalImageWidth = 0;

        $(".image-div", this).each(function () {
          totalImageWidth += $(this).width();
        });

        if (totalImageWidth < $(document.body).width() ) {
           $(this).attr('id', 'makeMeScrollable2');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way of making something like the following line work: if (totalImageWidth - 1000 < $(document.body).width() ) {

Comment: No, it didn't work for me. Im assuming ive written it incorrectly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [parseint](http://www.minihowtos.net/jquery-parseint) function :)